# FTP Download estimate time remaining

Tags: c#, ftp

I'm making a simple program that downloads a bunch of files. Now i want to show the user "xx time remaining" (like you see with uTorrent).

So far this is what i got

**Downloading the file**

```
// Download the file
//Console.WriteLine("Downloading \"{0}\" from {1}...", node.Name, Config.FTP_HOST + "/" + node.DirectoryFileIsIn);
FtpWebRequest request = CreateRequest("ftp://" + Config.FTP_HOST + "/" + node.DirectoryFileIsIn + "/" + node.Name, WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile.ToString());
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
FileStream filestream = new FileStream(new_path, FileMode.Create);

int chunkSize = 1024;
long total = node.FileSize;
int streamPosition = 0;
while (true)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[Math.Min(chunkSize, node.FileSize - streamPosition)];
    //byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
    int readBytes = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    if (readBytes == 0)
        break;

    currentFileSizeDownloaded += readBytes; // total bytes downloaded
    bytesSnapshot += readBytes; // for tracking download speed
    streamPosition += readBytes; // for tracking response stream position

    filestream.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
}

filestream.Flush();
//Console.WriteLine("Download Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

response.Dispose();
filestream.Dispose();

response.Close();
filestream.Close();
```

**Capturing bytes downloaded (seperate Thread)**

```
// Calculate total download time
public static void CalculateDownloadTime()
{
    bytesSnapshot = 0;
    int waitTime = 10000;
    Thread.Sleep(waitTime); // sleep 10 seconds

    if (bytesSnapshot > 0)
    {
        double downloadSpeed = (bytesSnapshot / 10); // bytes per second
        long remainingTime = (totalFileSizeToDownload - currentFileSizeDownloaded) / (long)downloadSpeed;
        Console.WriteLine("Download speed {0}", Formatting.FormatBytes((long)downloadSpeed));
        Console.WriteLine("Remaining time {0}", Formatting.FormatSeconds(remainingTime));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("byteSnapshot = 0"); // DEBUG
        downloadTracker.Abort();
        return;
    }

    CalculateDownloadTime();
}
```

**Output**

```
Download speed 106,73 KB
Remaining time 0:01:52

Download speed 9,02 KB
Remaining time 0:22:05

Download speed 8,94 KB
Remaining time 0:22:06

Download speed 7,68 KB
Remaining time 0:25:35

Download speed 7,68 KB
Remaining time 0:25:25

Download speed 8,12 KB
Remaining time 0:23:52

Download speed 8,39 KB
Remaining time 0:22:56

Download speed 169,65 KB
Remaining time 0:00:58

Download speed 591,03 KB
Remaining time 0:00:06

Download speed 393,86 KB
Remaining time 0:00:00

byteSnapshot = 0
```

As you can see i'm doing something wrong.. The download speed doesnt look realistic to me and the time is way off, but i can't figure out what is going wrong here..

I think my problem lies with the calculation of the download speed, so the time would be fixed if the download speed is correct...

Answer (score 0):

**I've been testing and i think i found a solution.**

I created 2 `BackgroundWorkers`

1. Downloading process
2. Calculate download speed

**Downloading process**
Nothing much changed here.. I added a `Stopwatch` to keep track of the time it took to download x amount of bytes. The x amount of bytes are stored in `currentFileSizeDownloaded` and the seconds are stored in `secondsElapsed`.

```
// Download the file
//Console.WriteLine("Downloading \"{0}\" from {1}...", node.Name, Config.FTP_HOST + "/" + node.DirectoryFileIsIn);
FtpWebRequest request = CreateRequest("ftp://" + Config.FTP_HOST + "/" + node.DirectoryFileIsIn + "/" + node.Name, WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile.ToString());
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
FileStream filestream = new FileStream(new_path, FileMode.Create);

// Start stopwatch for calculating download speed
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();

// Read/write downloaded bytes
int chunkSize = 1024;
long total = node.FileSize;
int streamPosition = 0;
while (true)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[Math.Min(chunkSize, node.FileSize - streamPosition)];
    //byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
    int readBytes = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    if (readBytes == 0)
        break;

    currentFileSizeDownloaded += readBytes; // total bytes downloaded
    streamPosition += readBytes; // for tracking response stream position

    filestream.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
}

// Stop the stopwatch
stopwatch.Stop();
secondsElapsed += stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;

filestream.Flush();
//Console.WriteLine("Download Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

response.Dispose();
filestream.Dispose();

response.Close();
filestream.Close();
}
```

**Calculate download speed**
This is where i calculate the download speed, again nothing much changed.. I'm caching `secondsElapsed`, `currentFileSizeDownloaded` from the Downloading process and use these exact values for my DownloadSpeed calculation (instead of using the '10 seconds' from my `Thread.Sleep()`).

```
while (true)
{
    cached_secondsElapsed = secondsElapsed;
    cached_currentFileSizeDownloaded = currentFileSizeDownloaded;

    Thread.Sleep(10000); // Sleep 10 seconds

    long bytesDownloaded = currentFileSizeDownloaded - cached_currentFileSizeDownloaded;
    double secondsItTook = secondsElapsed - cached_secondsElapsed;

    if (bytesDownloaded > 0)
    {
        double downloadSpeed = ((double)bytesDownloaded / secondsItTook); // bytes per second
        long remainingTime = (totalFileSizeToDownload - currentFileSizeDownloaded) / (long)downloadSpeed;
        Console.WriteLine("Download speed {0}", Formatting.FormatBytes((long)downloadSpeed));
        Console.WriteLine("Remaining time {0}", Formatting.FormatSeconds(remainingTime));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("bytesDownloaded = 0"); // DEBUG
        Application.Exit(); // Stop the app
    } 
}
```

**Output**

```
Download speed 976,58 KB
Remaining time 0:00:12

Download speed 438,6 KB
Remaining time 0:00:27

Download speed 483,37 KB
Remaining time 0:00:24

Download speed 325,42 KB
Remaining time 0:00:36

Download speed 331,42 KB
Remaining time 0:00:35

Download speed 363,87 KB
Remaining time 0:00:31

Download speed 441,13 KB
Remaining time 0:00:26

Download speed 798,81 KB
Remaining time 0:00:10

Download speed 1,04 MB
Remaining time 0:00:00

bytesDownloaded = 0
```

It is not that accurate, but it is waaay better than what i had before.. If anyone has any Tips for me on getting this output more accurate, please post them as an answer/comment.